# iOS CallKit Advertising integration

Tags: ios, integration, ads, callkit

Is it possible to integrate advertisings in this screen:

[image]

between "Hotline Audio..." and "Remind me" button ?

Comment: hi, please check this link https://www.ios-blog.com/tutorials/swift/display-ads-in-your-application-with-google-admob/

Answer (score 5):

No, this screen is the OS's system UI and there is no API for controlling it. You can find everything you do have control over [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit). In the documentation it states that CallKit only lets you show the system UI for calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance which phone number(s) the incoming calls will originate from, a very dirty trick you could use is to add a contact to the Address Book. You could technically get an image to appear there by adding it as a profile picture to the address book card. If the image is large enough, the iPhone will display it full screen.

On a side note, I am quite sure this won't get through App Store Review, without even mentioning the fact that your users will be very pissed if you show them advertisements there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display ad banners on incoming call screen provided by CallKit framework. But you can display an ad on any other call screen that your app provides instead.